# How to check which network interface is active and providing internet?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, internet

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 500
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

how do perform a check which network interface is active and providing internet and internet is working on that interface.
In the above `lo`(loopback interface),`eno1`(ethernet interface),`wlp2s0`(wireless) are up but i am getting internet only from `wlp2s0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fairly good way is to check the routing table to see where the default routing goes

```
ip route list | grep default
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do perform a check which network interface is active

Any of the interfaces saying `state UP` are active, and providing connectivity to some network or another.

> and providing internet and internet is working on that interface.

You are really asking about just how approximately does ip routing work, and there is a lot of depth to that question.  In essence, the routing table is a list of different networks with masks, and what network interface or external router provides connectivity to them.

At the end of this list is a special entry called the `default route`, which is kind of an alias for the network 0.0.0.0/0.  It functions as a catch-all for things that you have no specific entry for, and in essence is the internet.

You can see the routing table by typing `ip route`.  It will provide some explanation of what interfaces are used for different addresses, and show the mighty default route.

Answer (score -1):

simply type `route`. It should give you the active Net providing interface's details.

Comment: Well, my bad I am supposed to explain. cause above command's outputs have to be checked with another command. Anyway, simply type `route`. It should provide you the details of ip and interface.